# Why does jQuery load() use a dummy div internally?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Seen in the jQuery source for the `load()` function, after the response is received:

```
        self.html( selector ?

            // If a selector was specified, locate the right elements in a dummy div
            // Exclude scripts to avoid IE 'Permission Denied' errors
            jQuery("<div>").append( jQuery.parseHTML( responseText ) ).find( selector ) :

            // Otherwise use the full result
            responseText );
```

What is meant by *"locate the right elements in a dummy div"*? Why is a dummy div needed at all?

Comment: It is not part of the ajax code... but part of load method

Comment: Sorry you are right, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not part of the ajax code, but part of the `load()` method which allows to load a fragment of the response content.

The temp element is created so that when the fragment is queried, if it is the topmost element then that also is fetched else the `find()` method will exclude the root element. Then you will need to use a combination of `filter`/`find()` to do that.

Ex: If the response is `<div class="result">....</div>` and the selector is `.result` then if we use `$(responseText ).find(selector)`, it will fail since the `result` is not  a descendant of the element, but the root, so just adding the response as a descendant of a temp element you have the html as `<div><div class="result">....</div></div>`, now by just using `find('.result')` the proper element is returned.

Comment: So let's say I'm writing that snippet myself, but I know what the element is. Then I suppose I can bypass all this and just write `$('#element').html($.parseHTML(responseText));` ?

Comment: @Gigi Bypass what? If you use `load()` method, it would add it twice. If you use e.g `$.get()`, then ya. But so, why not using `load()`?!

Comment: @Arun  Any reason it's using `append()`, not `html()`?

Comment: @A.Wolff No no, I said "say I'm writing that snippet myself", i.e. not relying on the `load()` method. Just doing an `$.ajax()` request and processing the result.

Comment: In other words, I just want to confirm that the way it's written is because it's flexible across different possible selectors, and this doesn't apply if you know the element beforehand.

Comment: @Gigi yes.... if you don't want to use `.load` and just want to use `ajax` to load content then yes

Comment: @A.Wolff not sure... need to have a deeper look

Comment: @Gigi So ya if you don't care about page fragment

Comment: @Gigi you could just say `$('#element').html(responseText);` that is what is executed if the `selector` is not passed - look at the ternary operator

Comment: @ArunPJohny you don't even need the `parseHTML()`?

Comment: Just to put things in context, I'm asking because I found that `.load()` doesn't work cross-domain (even if the server sends back `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`). But doing the same `$.ajax()` thing does work.

Comment: @Gigi I don't think that should be a problem since the `load` method also is using ajax... check your browser console to see what is the error

Comment: Agreed, it's strange, but in practice I found that with `load()` the request doesn't get through (it doesn't even appear in the Network tab), and no errors in the console.

Answer (score 2):

This has to be done if the `response` is in `xmlstring/htmlstring` and you can find an element directly in it.

See,

```
jQuery("<div>")
      .append(jQuery.parseHTML(responseText))
      .find( selector )
```

Take it line by line:

1. Create a virtual div in memory to hold the `xml/html` data.
2. `.append()` the `xml` data as a valid html with `jQuery.parseHTML()` method.
3. Now you can find a specific element in it.